# palabra clave no admitida 'provider'

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hola buen dia estoy desarrollando un sistema ABC todo lo hago con SQl Connection y funcionaba perfecto pero encontre un codigo para validar si habia un registro en la base de datos con el mismo nombre este ejemplo usaba un OleDb(en si funciona) pero a la hora de querer modificar un registro me sale el error del titulo de la publicacion.

Les dejo el codigo que uso:

Esto es para el update

```
Dim cnn As New SqlConnection 
Dim conexion As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=servidor;Initial Catalog=BD;user id = user; password = pass"
cnn = New SqlConnection(conexion)
            cnn.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("modlin", cnn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idline", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox2.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@lin", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@prens", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxPrensa.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@diin", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_diamin.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@diex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbdiamex.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pes_roll", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_pesroll.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fech", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Registro Modificado")
            ComboBox1.Text = ""
            TextBoxPrensa.Text = ""
            DateTimePicker1.Text = ""
            ComboBox2.Text = ""
            tb_diamin.Text = ""
            tbdiamex.Text = ""
            tb_pesroll.Text = ""
            ErrorProvider1.Clear()
            ComboBox1.Text = ""
            TextBoxPrensa.Text = ""
            DateTimePicker1.Text = ""
            ComboBox2.Text = ""
            tb_diamin.Text = ""
            tbdiamex.Text = ""
            tb_pesroll.Text = ""
            ErrorProvider1.Clear()
```

esto es lo que uso para la validacion:

```
Dim consultaSQL As String = "SELECT linea from linea where linea ='" & Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString & "'"

    Dim Da As New OleDbDataAdapter(consultaSQL, conexion)
    Dim Dt As New DataTable
    Da.Fill(Dt)
    If Dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        MessageBox.Show("Linea Duplicada Intente Con Otra... (Ignore Este Mensaje Si Va A Modificar El Registro)")
        BtnRegis.Enabled = False
    Else
        BtnRegis.Enabled = True
    End If
```

Ojala y me puedan ayudar, gracias...

Comment: Necesitamos saber a que base de datos estás intentado conectarte (SqlServer, MySql, Access...)

Answer (score 2):

El Conection string tiene que ser:

```
Dim connectionString AS String = "Server=my_server;Database=name_of_db;User Id=user_name;Password=my_password"
```

el conection string que usas es para OleDb